# route displays contents of new component beneath existing component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a dashboard component below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, Route, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

import NewComponent from './newComponent';

const DashboardComponent = () => {
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={`${url}/new`}>Post</Link>
      <div>
        <h4>Title Goes Here.</h4>
      <Route path={`${url}/new-job`}><NewComponent /></Route>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DashboardComponent;
```

What happens with this is that when I click on Post link the url changes fine but the contents of the `NewComponent` are displayed beneath `Title Goes Here`. I only want to see only `NewComponent`'s contents so it should replace `DashboardComponent`'s contents with NewComponent. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace ethe dashboard component, your Route should be placed outside of the Dashboard component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import NewComponent from './newComponent';

const DashboardComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={`/new-job`}>Post</Link>
      <div>
        <h4>Title Goes Here.</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DashboardComponent;

const App = () => {
   return (
       <BrowserRouter>
           <Route path="dashboard"><DashBoardComponent</Route>
           <Route path={`/new-job`}><NewComponent /></Route>
       </BrowserRouter>
   )
}
```

Comment: With this approach I will have to replace the url. I want to add `/new-job` to current url in the browser.

Comment: You can define any path for the Route such as `/dashboard/new-job`, just that in this case you would need to use a exact attribute on Route to avoid partial match

Comment: can you give me example?